# Match headers in markdown

Tags: regex, powershell, markdown

I try to create a function that parses markdown files and returns table of contents. The toc will than have dynamic references to the specific headers inside the markdown file.

I'm currently trying to figure out, how to match the header correctly.

My example.md:

```
Setex-Header layer 1
========================================================

Setex-Header layer 2
------------

### Atx-Header layer 3

#### Atx-Header layer 4
```

RegEx-Strings I tried so far:

```
$atxMatcher = '(^\s*(?<ATXlayer>#+)\s*(?<ATXname>.+)$)'
$setexMatcher = '\s*(?<setexname>[\w|\d\s]+)\n(?<setexLayer>[-|=]+)\n'
$regexString = '(^\s*(?<atxlayer>#+)\s*(?<atxname>.+)$)|(^\s*(?<setexname>[\w|\d\s]+)\n(?<setexLayer>[-|=]+)$)'
```

I think the best chances are going with `select-string` or `Foreach-Object`.

Select-String may work, if I pass in the files contents as a string. But I can't figure out the correct regex-string to match the headers.

Foreach-Object could work, but needs a lot more logic, if I want to handle setex-headers too, as they are multiline.

Expected outcome should be about

```
$matches.SetexLayer = '============================'
$matches.SetexHeader = 'Setex-Header layer 1'

$matches.SetexLayer = '----------------------------'
$matches.SetexHeader = 'Setex-Header layer 2'


$matches.atxLayer = '###'
$matches.atxHeader = 'Atx-Header layer 3'

$matches.atxLayer = '####'
$matches.atxHeader = 'Atx-Header layer 4'
```

Any ideas how to make that regex-string?

Comment: What is the exact expected output? What is an example of a multiline setex header and how can you define its boundaries?

Comment: Your [ATX regex works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5e%5cs*%28%3f%3cATXlayer%3e%23%2b%29%5cs*%28%3f%3cATXname%3e.%2b%29%24%29&i=Setex-Header+layer+1%0d%0a%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a%0d%0aSetex-Header+layer+2%0d%0a------------%0d%0a%0d%0a%23%23%23+Atx-Header+layer+3%0d%0a%0d%0a%23%23%23%23+Atx-Header+layer+4&o=m).

Comment: For setex, please check [`^Setex-(?<setexname>[\w\s]+)\r?\n(?<setexLayer>([-=])\1+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eSetex-%28%3f%3csetexname%3e%5b%5cw%5cs%5d%2b%29%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f%3csetexLayer%3e%28%5b-%3d%5d%29%5c1%2b%29&i=Setex-Header+layer+1%0d%0a%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a%0d%0aSetex-Header+layer+2%0d%0a------------%0d%0a%0d%0a%23%23%23+Atx-Header+layer+3%0d%0a%0d%0a%23%23%23%23+Atx-Header+layer+4&o=m)

Comment: I would use an actual Markdown parser for this.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that would be easier... but it's not powershell ;) (btw: nice job @PSConfEU)

Comment: Thanks. FWIW Regex is also not PowerShell ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [correct regex-string](https://regex101.com/r/m9s5oW/1).

`'((?<atxlayer>#+)\s*(?<atxname>.+))|((?<setexname>[\w|\d|\s|-]+)\n(?<setexLayer>[-|=]{2,}))'` matches all accourances like I wanted to.

I'll give you an update on the function, maybe it'll come in handy.

I think, I will split the md to exclude fenced code blocks.

**Update 1**

Ok, I redone the string, because it was not as good as I initialy thougt.

Now I have `(?<name>[^\n\r]+)\n(?<Layer>[-|=]{2,})$|^((?<layer>#{1,6})\s*(?<name>.+))$`.

```
#Setex-Section
(?<name>[^\n\r]+) #everything but linebreak and carriage return
\n #linebreak
(?<Layer>[-|=]{2,})$ #---- or ==== and end of line -> multiline option

| -> Or

#ATX-Section
^((?<layer>#{1,6}) #start of line and # - ######
\s* #optional whitespaces
(?<name>.+))$ #everything until end of line
```

Works perfectly at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/m9s5oW/4) when I activate the multiline-option.

[RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Cname%3E%5B%5E%5Cn%5Cr%5D%2B%29%5Cn%28%3F%3CLayer%3E%5B-%7C%3D%5D%7B2%2C%7D%29%24%7C%5E%28%28%3F%3Clayer%3E%23%7B1%2C6%7D%29%5Cs*%28%3F%3Cname%3E.%2B%29%29%24&i=Setex-Header1%20layer%201%0D%0A%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%0D%0ASetex-Header2%20layer%202%0D%0A------------%0D%0A%0D%0ASetex-Header3%20layer%202%0D%0A------------%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%23%20Atx-Header1%20layer%203%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%23%23%20Atx-Header2%20layer%204%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%23%23%20Atx-Header3%20layer%204%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%23%23%20Atx-Header4%20layer%204%0D%0A%0D%0A&o=m) however (and `[regex]::matches()` method too) seem to work different.

Here an update on my example code:

```
$string = @'

Setex-Header1 layer 1
========================================================

Setex-Header2 layer 2
------------

Setex-Header3 layer 2
------------

### Atx-Header1 layer 3

#### Atx-Header2 layer 4

#### Atx-Header3 layer 4

#### Atx-Header4 layer 4


'@


$regex = '(?<name>[^\n\r]+)\n(?<Layer>[-|=]{2,})$|^((?<layer>#{1,6})\s*(?<name>.+))$'

$options = [text.regularexpressions.regexoptions]::Multiline

[regex]::Matches($string, $regex, $options).value
```

**Update 2**
Now my [regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%3F%3Cname%3E%5B%5E%5Cn%5Cr%5D%2B%29%5Cr%5Cn%28%3F%3CLayer%3E%5B-%7C%3D%5D%7B2%2C%7D%29%29%7C%28%28%3F%3Clayer%3E%23%7B1%2C6%7D%29%5Cs*%28%3F%3Cname%3E.%2B%29%29&i=Setex-Header1%20layer%201%0D%0A%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%0D%0ASetex-Header2%20layer%202%0D%0A------------%0D%0A%0D%0ASetex-Header3%20layer%202%0D%0A------------%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%23%20Atx-Header1%20layer%203%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%23%23%20Atx-Header2%20layer%204%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%23%23%20Atx-Header3%20layer%204%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%23%23%20Atx-Header4%20layer%204%0D%0A%0D%0A&o=m) works on regexstorm, but still does not match in powershell, while using the option `multiline`.

Here the string: `((?<name>[^\n\r]+)\r\n(?<Layer>[-|=]{2,}))|((?<layer>#{1,6})\s*(?<name>.+))`

Any Ideas what to do?

**Update 3**

I just found out, that the matches work like a charm, but only if I use a here-string as input to match. If I use get content on a sample file, the results do not match. I'm trying to figure out, whats wrong here - somebody else expierenced thist behavior?

**update 4: solution**

I could go around that here-string or get-content issue by using `Get-Content` and ``` -join "``n" ``` (only one backtick here) which lead to a working solution.

The working function is now avaiable at [github](https://github.com/bgraeb/helpers/tree/master/markdown)